# NSView file drag zone (copy to finder)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag, nsview

I'm trying to create a drag view where you can drag a file off, which the app generates. It's a subclass of `NSImageView` and I have written this method so far:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)pTheEvent {
    NSPoint tvarMouseInWindow = [pTheEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint tvarMouseInView   = [self convertPoint:tvarMouseInWindow fromView:nil];

    NSSize zDragOffset = NSMakeSize(0, 0);
    NSPasteboard *zPasteBoard;

    zPasteBoard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
    [zPasteBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSTIFFPboardType] owner:self];
    [zPasteBoard setData:[[self image] TIFFRepresentation] forType:NSTIFFPboardType];

    [self dragImage:[self image] at:tvarMouseInView offset:zDragOffset event:pTheEvent pasteboard:zPasteBoard source:self slideBack:YES];

    return;
}
```

When I now drag the contained image off the imageView and try to drop it into a Finder window, it just slides back and does not copy. How do I implement file drag (not drop!) zones with `NSView` properly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after a bit trial and error and looking at all methods the `NSView` provides. Here is the correct one:

```
[self dragFile:myFile fromRect:[self bounds] slideBack:YES event:pTheEvent];
```

Of cause I have to create a "file" and not and instance of `UIImage`. But my app generates files and this is what I want anyway!